# Atualizar nested array no mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Olá,

Eu tenho procurado por uma solução para o meu problema, cujo vou referir abaixo, mas ainda não encontrei a maneira certa de o resolver, as soluções que eu encontro normalmente atualizam a array toda invés de alguns elementos em específico.

**Problema:**

```js
const user = await Users.getById(userID); // Um documento da coleção

for (let item of items) {
    const index = user.inventory.findIndex(element => element.id == item.id);

    if (index > -1) {
        user.inventory[index].quantity += item.quantity;
    } else {
        user.inventory.push(item);
    }
}

user.markModified('inventory');
await user.save();
```

Eu quero fazer apenas uma requisição ao banco de dados e não duas como o meu código está atualmente a fazer, uma requisição para obter o documento e outra para salvar.

Answer (score 0):

A API javascript do mongodb fornece os métodos `updateOne` e `updateMany`, os quais aceitam a chave `$set` pra fazer atualizações parciais.

Verificar:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/

Se você está utilizando o mongoose, `updateOne` e `updateMany` estão registrados como propriedades do `Model`:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.updateOne

Quando consultando a documentação do mongoose geralmente você não vai encontrar a informação completa, tem que consultar também na documentação do mongo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas eu já estou familiarizado com esses métodos, entretanto não consegui encontrar nenhum query operator na documentação do mongo para o meu processo.

Comment: $set não serve?